# Free web host with an open TCP port? (needed 4 websockets)

Tags: tcp, port, web-hosting, websocket

I'm working on a HTML5 project with websockets and canvas, and I hit a brick wall. Can't find any server with an open TCP port I can use for the websockets.

I' talking about something like this:

```
this._connection = new WebSocket("ws://81.213.217.144:8005");
```

I tried looking for a port on my college's server, but they've got all theirs closed (except for a UDP port which is useless for me here). Also tried 000webhost.com, no luck.

Does anyone know (if there are) any free web hosts with open TCP ports?

PS: my ISP will pretty much not allow me setting up a server at home. all ports are hidden/blocked/whatever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty much all hosting companies allow you to run services on port 80 and 443 (web ports). You should be able to run a WebSockets server on one of those ports. The [pywebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/) project can run as a standalone WebSockets server or as a module with Apache which would allow you to server WebSockets on the same port that you are serving web pages.

Alternate if you just need to be able to send messages between WebSockets clients (i.e. you don't need a special WebSockets server), you can try using [pusherapp](http://pusherapp.com/). They allow you to have up to 5 WebSockets clients at a time for free.

Comment: OMG I did not know about pusherapp. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Set up your own server on your computer, and configure it bind to only IP 127.0.0.1. Then it won't leak off your machine and upset your ISP.

You can do all the development work you want, and move to a real web host when it is time to deploy the project. ([Linode](http://www.linode.com/) and other VPS providers can be pretty affordable if your needs are meager.)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose, but that's a localhost, right? so it'll just work on my pc.